Module federation without using a monorepo?
Currently I am building a micro-frontend to be added to an existing larger application. These 2 applications are hosted on different Github repositories, and the micro-frontend is working well through module federation. Im able to load the remote app into the shell.
However, I want to share NgRx state, simple custom services, etc.. between these 2 remote applications. Is it possible using module federation? For example, am I able to create a small service in my remote app and "expose" it to my shell app? Do I have to make a library for this and host it externally? I'm totally lost at this simple step.
All the examples I have seen online use a monorepo and I can't figure out how to do this with 2 remote repositories.
Any help would be appreciated

Need more details. So many people just think "I'll just create a third party package and make it a dependency of both my module and my shell" and drastically underestimate the maintenance effort (and discipline) required to actually make that work reasonably well without feeling like you're overcoupling it to one thing, or the other, or both. Sharing state is as simple as passing data into the microfrontend and having the shell attach event listeners. Do you actually want to share code? Or do you just want to expose an API interface (from the shell to the module)?

I want to share code. If I create a simple console.log helper function in a service inside my remote app, I want to 'expose' this helper function to my shell app to call.  Or vice versa, I made a helper function service in my shell and share it with my remote app. Can this be achieved? I see tutorials where people share an HTML component through a module, but I want to share a TypeScript file essentially

You you can do this. Module Federation doe not need to be in same repository. You can do POC on it. Create Shared Library which uses same Instance of service between host and shell
